Does the UNSC publish a list of the emergency meetings?
According to this article, "UN Security Council schedules emergency meeting at request of Israel and France"

UNITED NATIONS — The UN Security Council has scheduled an emergency meeting on the escalating situation in the Middle East for Wednesday at 10 a.m. local time, at the request of France and Israel.

Is there a place where I can find more information about this meeting? What's the agenda for the meeting? Is any of this published on the UNSC website?

Not my DV. Slighly weird that they already had a Middle East meeting scheduled for today https://main.un.org/securitycouncil/sites/default/files/2024/monthly_pow2024-10.pdf I'm not sure when that doc was updated. I think agendas are not published in advance in anymore detail than that. Once the meeting gets going, the chair will probably announce the more detailed agenda.

Also there's a video of the meeting here now: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1VyjPJclLAI

If it's anything like with resolutions, full text takes a while to be posted.

It appears on the UN Security Council's Programme of Work as "9738th meeting - Middle East".
As mentioned in a comment elsewhere, this appears to have been in the schedule already, though it's not clear when this was added, nor whether the meeting will now have a different agenda from the planned one.
Any outcomes of that meeting (which may be in the form of a press statement, or possibly a resolution if one is agreed) will appear on the Decisions and Outcomes page.
